# Jquery Datepicker can't go to previous month when mindate is set

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is the title says, if I set `MiDate: "+4D"` and if that day is in the next month for example:
Today is 28.09 and + 4 days is 02.10. This way clicking on previous month arrow does nothing. It is restricted. This is how my js looks:

```
function dateFrom(date_from, date_to) {
        let todayDate = new Date()
        let numberOfDaysToAdd = 4
        todayDate.setDate(todayDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 
        $(date_from).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
            prevText: 'letzter Monat',
            nextText: 'nächster Monat',
            minDate: "+4d",
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                var dateParts = selectedDate.split('.');
                var result = new Date(dateParts[2] + '-' + dateParts[1] + '-' + dateParts[0]);
                result.setDate(result.getDate() + 10);
                $(date_to).datepicker("option", "minDate", result);
                $(date_to).datepicker("show");
            }
        })
        .datepicker({
            "setDate": todayDate,
            'currentText': 'Check-in'
        })
    }
```

To reproduce the problem you can simply create a datepicker and add the `MinDate` property to overlap in the next month.

Comment: the essence of having `minDate` OR `maxDate` means you go NOT back to previous months or previous dates at all.

Comment: And what if I need to ? I understand the essence but there is always different situations.